# Difficulties upgrading from Windows Server 2003 R2 to Windows Server 2008 R2 with an "Incompatibility issue" using the disk

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003

I currently have have Windows Server 2003 R2 and am looking to upgrade to Windows Server 2008 R2. When I insert the Windows Server 2008 disk, it gives me the following error:

> The installation disc isn't compatible with your version of Windows.
>   To upgrade, you need the correct installation disk.

**What I think the possibilities could be:**

My Windows Server 2003 edition may have 32-bit in architecture. I can’t really tell as when I time in “`winver`”, it just tells me the Server data information and System does not tell me if it’s x86 or x64. Could this possibly be a cross-architecture upgrade failure?

I don't know how to go about this, honestly. What would you recommend?

Comment: Run `msinfo32` and look at the System Type. If you're running 32bit Windows Server 2003 then you can't upgrade to 64bit Windows Server whatever.

Comment: Got it, thanks! I'll update once I gather more data.